# Angular 2 hide an item

Tags: angular

when I can this  I want to hide only the row selected ...But this method below hide the whole table.. Any idea?

```
    <tr *ngFor="let coll of pagedItems">
<template [ngIf]="hide">    
 <td><i title="Editer le Collaborateur" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalNorm" class="ion-edit ion-white" [class.selected]="isSelected(coll)" (click)="EditColl(coll)"></i>
                <i title="Supprimer le Collaborateur" (click)="DeleteColl(coll)"  class="ion-trash-a"></i></td>

             <td hidden>{{coll.id}}</td>
             <td>{{coll.cin}}</td>
             <td>{{coll.lastname | uppercase}}</td>
             <td>{{coll.firstname}}</td>
             <td>{{coll.email | lowercase}}</td>
             <td>{{coll.datenaissance }}</td>
             <td>{{coll.dateembauche}}</td>
             </template>
            </tr>
```

Comment: You're using a boolean variable `hide`, in order to know if a specific row should be hidden. That can't possibly work. How could you know, from a boolean variable, *which* row must be hidden? How about using a variable containing *the row* that must be hidden, instead? And why do you hide the tds instead of hiding the tr?

Comment: you need to hide which row

Answer (score 0):

You should move out the template outside the tr element, do the ngFor there and put an ngIf for each row, based on a flag to determine whether to show or not the row:

```
<tbody>
  <template ngFor let-coll [ngForOf]="pagedItems" [ngForTrackBy]="id">
    <tr *ngIf="coll.active">
        <td><i title="Editer le Collaborateur" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalNorm" class="ion-edit ion-white" [class.selected]="isSelected(coll)" (click)="editColl(coll)"></i>
        <button (click)="deleteColl(coll); $event.preventDefault()">Supprimer le Collaborateur</button></td>

         <td hidden>{{coll.id}}</td>
         <td>{{coll.cin}}</td>
         <td>{{coll.lastname | uppercase}}</td>
         <td>{{coll.firstname}}</td>
         <td>{{coll.email | lowercase}}</td>
         <td>{{coll.datenaissance }}</td>
         <td>{{coll.dateembauche}}</td>
     </tr>
  </template>
</tbody>
```

You can see it working [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/viQaUSqixcr3mRukZclA?p=preview)